# move the screen content to the left outside the screen android

Tags: android, layout

is there a way to move the whole screen content outside the screen bounds, with titlebar and all, on the left for example, i tried

```
content = ((LinearLayout) act.findViewById(android.R.id.content)
                .getParent());
```

to get the screen content and add a margin to it

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams pr = (android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams) content
                    .getLayoutParams();
            pr.rightMargin = xOffset;
            content.setLayoutParams(pr);
```

but it doesnt work, the margin appears but the content is not moved just resized to fit the screen, anyone know how to do this the simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the margin in negative(-) values.
for example if your want the layout to move upper use this:

```
android:marginTop = "-50dip or more u can put"
```

Comment: i managed to get it to work by setting margin left = -offset, margin right = offset

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to flip between views? As in, moving that layout off the screen to show another one? If so you should look at using a widget called `ViewFlipper` which will do exactly as you need. It can also be animated etc.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html